# How to terminate currently runnig quartz job with overriding interrupt method that's coming from InterruptableJob interface?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I have some quartz jobs to process some data. I used InterruptableJob interface when writing these jobs. I have to add an interrupt feature to these jobs. When user press the terminate button, this method calling:

```
@Override
protected void immediatelyTerminate() {

    try {

        String fireInstanceIdToKillJob = "";

        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        List<JobExecutionContext> currentlyExecutingJobs = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();

        for(JobExecutionContext jec : currentlyExecutingJobs) {
            if(jec.getJobDetail().getKey().getName().contains(specificJobKey) {
                fireInstanceIdToKillJob = jec.getFireInstanceId();
            }
        }

        scheduler.interrupt(fireInstanceIdToKillJob);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("error in immediatelyTerminate() method:" + e);
    }
}
```

scheduler.interrupt calls the interrupt() method that is overridden in a class and this class has also execute method. The class that has overridden interrupt method is like this:

```
private Thread threadToKill;

@Override
public void execute() {
  threadToKill = Thread.currentThread();
}

@Override
public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException {
    try {
        threadToKill.interrupt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception handled "+e);
    }   
}
```

But with this code the job doesn't terminate, it continues to working. threadToKill.interrupt(); line doesn't actually terminate the running job.

How can I terminate runnig job?

Answer (score 0):

I got to implement this very same functionality a couple years ago.

[Interrupting a thread does not kill it nor stop it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html). It just activates a flag so the thread knows it has been *asked* to stop. Most internal methods will check for this and throw an `InterruptedException` for you to catch it, but some threads will happily ignore any interruption requests.
So, it's up to the job itself to detect this scenario and act accordingly.

Basically, your `interrupt()` method should set some flag to `true`, and your job should check this flag from time to time and stop whatever it's doing when it notices the flag is active.
This is how I implemented it:

```
public clas SomeJob implements InterruptableJob {

    protected AtomicBoolean stopFlag = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Override
    public void execute(final JobExecutionContext context) {
        for (Item item : listOfItems) { // whatever long tasks(s) you are doing,
            if (stopFlag.get()) {       // just check for this on every main loop
                logger.error("Job interrupted! Leaving at item: "+item);
                break;
            }
            performTask(item);
        }
        cleanUp();
        return;
    }

    private void performTask(Item item) {
        for(....) {               // another loop,
            if (stopFlag.get()) { // another check
                // ....
                return; // or break, depending on each case
            }
            someInternalProcessing(...);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void interrupt() {
        stopFlag.set(true);
    }
}
```

That's it. Just make sure to clean up, close connections etc. before aborting.